# Перехват копирования текста в буфер

Tags: qt5, clipboard

Необходимо отлавливать момент копирования текста в буфер из любого приложения, получать этот текст и делать определённое действие. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? На просторах интернета ничего не нашёл (плохо искал?)

Comment: qt тут вряд ли поможет. Можно, наверное, написать софтину, которая будет получать буфер с определенной периодичностью. Но как-то это на троя похоже...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример небольшого наблюдателя за буфером обмена

```
#include <QClipboard>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

class ClipboardWatcher : public QTextEdit{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClipboardWatcher(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QTextEdit(parent)
    {
        connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()),
                this, SLOT(_setClipboardText()));
        setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    }
private slots:
    void _setClipboardText(){
        setText(QApplication::clipboard()->text());
    }
};
```

[image]
[image]